# Set environment variable from Azure Role to use in PHP

Tags: php, azure, environment-variables

I'm using this code:
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString", connString, EnvironmentVariableTarget.[User|Process|Machine]);
on OnRoleEnvironmentChanged event of Azure RoleEntryPoint class to set a connection string on an Environment Var and use it in PHP but it doesn't work.

Using User or Process as target it simply doesn't work, using Machine the role cannot execute the instruction (maybe because of user restrictions)

How can I set variable from Azure Role in .NET to consume in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply use the `getConfigurationSettings()` method in the [Windows Azure PHP SDK](http://dl.windowsazure.com/phpdocs/classes/WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.html#init)? If you really want to set the environment variable, I suggest you try again with Machine but only after you changed the **executionContext** of your role to **elevated**.

Comment: It's exactly what I was searching for before choosing this solution. Do you have a sample or a link of how to use getConfigurationSettings()? Thank you

Comment: I've started the emulator then simply added the namespace and called the static function RoleEnvironment::getConfigurationSettings but I receive this exception: RoleEnvironmentNotAvailableException. If I call isEmulator I receive the same error

Comment: Also on the azure instance I get the RoleEnvironmentNotAvailableException exception. I called: RoleEnvironment::init();
then RoleEnvironment::getConfigurationSettings();

Comment: resolved using old php azure libraries (4.1.0) simply calling:  Microsoft_WindowsAzure_RoleEnvironment::getConfigurationSettingValue("settingName");